# How can I get the data that is sent from my html file to php and recieve and show the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I found a program which is sending the data from the form to php file from jquery. But when I have tried to find it, it is displaying nothing. When I am clicking on the Load Data button nothing is coming. Is something wrong in the program ?

main.php

```
<?php
if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
   $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
   echo "Welcome ". $name;
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js/"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
          $.post( 
             "main.php",
             { name: "Zara" },
             function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }

          );
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
   <div id="stage" style="">
          STAGE
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```

Please resolve the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: your url is `/jquery/result.php`, but the one you provided above is `main.php`

Comment: I have changed but still not working for me. Please help

Comment: @user3647254 Please update the question and use firebug or console to report errors you are getting.

Comment: Did you run on web server ? Can you see your post request on firebug console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` tag for loading jQuery has an invalid `href` attribute.
Remove the ending slash from the address so it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use your browser's developer tools to find out what's wrong with your clientside script, they're really handy. Hit F12.

Comment: @user3647254 Please mark my answer as the solution, then! We were happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#driver").click(function(event){
        $.post( "main.php", { name: "Zara"})
          .done(function( data ) {
             $('#stage').html(data);
          });
      });
   });
```

for detail see [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

Please the version of this file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js/"></script>
```

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>the title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   alert('hi');
      $("#driver").click(function(){

          $.post( 
             "main.php",
             { name: "Zara" },
             function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);
             }

          );
      });
   });
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <p>Click on the button to load result.html file:</p>
   <div id="stage" style="">
          STAGE
   </div>
   <input type="button" id="driver" value="Load Data" />
</body>
</html>
```